# Why my useEffect is working on localhost but not in production?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I am using the following logic in my app.jsx to check for accessToken and if is not there then I want to run useRefreshToken mutation to get new accessToken with the help of my stored refreshToken cookie stored as httpOnly and secure flag.

I am running the code successfully in my development and all is working as expected checked with console.logs at all the steps.

```
const [persist] = usePersist()
const token = useSelector(selectCurrentToken)
const effectRan = useRef(false)
const [trueSuccess, setTrueSuccess] = useState(false)

const [refresh, {
    isUninitialized,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    error
}] = useRefreshMutation()

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('verifying refresh token useffect running', token, persist)

    if (effectRan.current === true) {
        console.log('verifying refresh token effectRan.current')

        const verifyRefreshToken = async () => {
            console.log('verifying refresh token tryCatch running')
            try {
                await refresh()
                setTrueSuccess(true)
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.error(err)
            }
        }
     if (!token && persist) verifyRefreshToken()
     }

     return () => {
     console.log("EffectRan: ", effectRan.current, token, persist)
     effectRan.current = true
     console.log("EffectRan: ", effectRan.current)
     }
}, [])
```

However, when I deploy the application after "npm run build" only the first console.log runs indicating that useeffect is running but console.logs in the cleanup functions do not run. I am really pissed as this as I am stuck for more than 10 days. My mind cannot accept why a code is working fine in localhost but not on deployment. I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` is only setting the `effectRan.current` to `true` in the [cleanup function](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect#parameters).

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (effectRan.current === true) {
    // your logic
  }

  return () => {
    effectRan.current = true;
  };
}, []);
```

The fact that it only works in **developement** mode is because the `useEffect` [will run twice on mount](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect#my-effect-runs-twice-when-the-component-mounts) because of [StrictMode](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/StrictMode). So the `effectRan.current` will get set to `true` when the component unmounts for the first time and then when the it mounts again `effectRan.current` is `true`.

In **production** StrictMode is disabled and thus will not fire the `useEffect` twice.

Instead you could do something like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (effectRan.current === true) return;

  effectRan.current = true;
  // your logic
}, []);
```